# Find duplicates in an array and find their values (deep search) with Python

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of lines, with each line being represented by:

```
{
  'ms': int,
  'e_up': bool,
  'e_down': bool,
  'f_up': bool,
  'f_down': bool,
  'l_up': bool,
  'l_down': bool,
  'r_up': bool,
  'r_down': bool,
  'b': int,
  'a': int,
  'c': int,
  'd': int
}
```

I want to loop through all lines (an array of lines, as a dictionary) and find all duplicates and their .ms property.

For example, if I have:

`(1902, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, 128, -37, -127, -20)`

`(1843, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)`

`(1968, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)`

`(234, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)`

`(0, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)`

I want the output to be:

```
[
  [
    1843,
    1968,
    234,
    0
  ]
]
```

I want to find all possible combinations, and time isn't an issue here, if it took the extra time it wouldn't really matter to me. How can I accomplish this with Python? (No external libraries please)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved the problem was by searching each index with every other non-checked index of the array and finding the duplicates.

```
def find_duplicate(lines, line, duplicates, checked):
    if (line['ms'] in checked):
        return duplicates, checked

    duplicate = list()
    duplicate.append(line['ms'])

    checked.append(line['ms'])
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        new_line = lines[i]
        if new_line['ms'] in checked: continue
        if new_line['e_up'] == line['e_up'] and new_line['e_down'] == line['e_down'] and new_line['f_up'] == line['f_up'] and new_line['f_down'] == line['f_down'] and new_line['l_up'] == line['l_up'] and new_line['l_down'] == line['l_down'] and new_line['r_up'] == line['r_up'] and new_line['r_down'] == line['r_down'] and new_line['b'] == line['b'] and new_line['a'] == line['a'] and new_line['c'] == line['c'] and new_line['d'] == line['d']:
            duplicate.append(new_line['ms'])
            checked.append(new_line['ms'])

    duplicates.append(duplicate)

    return duplicates, checked
```

And then I used the above function on every non-checked index of the potential duplicate (lines) array.

```
duplicates = list()
checked = list()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    duplicates, checked = find_duplicate(lines, lines[i], duplicates, checked)

print(duplicates)
```

Input to the code:

```
(1902, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, 128, -37, -127, -20)
(1843, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)
(1932, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)
(1847, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)
(1869, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0)
```

Output:
`[[1902], [1843, 1932], [1847, 1869]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact the tuples can be used as keys in a dictionary. The following code uses the tuple of values other than 'ms' as a key in a dictionary, and the 'ms' values are saved as a list in the dictionary. Any list with 2 values or more indicates duplicates:

```py
itemlist = list()
itemlist.append((1902, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, 128, -37, -127, -20))
itemlist.append((1843, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0))
itemlist.append((1968, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0))
itemlist.append((234, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0))
itemlist.append((0, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0, 13, -13, 0))

itemdict = dict()
# create dictionary with lists of items according to signature
for item in itemlist:
    key = item[1:]
    if key in itemdict:
        itemdict[key].append(item[0])
    else:
        itemdict[key] = [item[0]]

# iterate over dictionary and find items with more than one occurence
duplicates = []
for value in itemdict.values():
    if len(value)>1:
        duplicates.extend(value)

print(duplicates)
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I want to be able to have multiple different duplicates, for example 2 duplicates, and another 3 duplicates, then the duplicates dict would be: [[1802, 1803], [1807, 1809]].

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to change `duplicates.extend(value)` to `duplicates.append(value)`. If that doesn't give the expected result, please provide a clearer example of inputs and outputs you expect.